# Error while deploying images on AWS EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, github-actions, devops

I am deploying my JavaScript app on an AWS EC2 instance using [GitHub Actions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GitHub#Scope), but this error occurs and the deploy job fails. How can I fix it?

**Error**:

```
Run echo "$PRIVATE_KEY" > private_key && chmod 600 private_key
Warning: Permanently added '***' (ED25519) to the list of known hosts.
Load key "private_key": error in libcrypto
***@***: Permission denied (publickey).
Error: Process completed with exit code 255.
```

Comment: Can you please add what have you tried to overcome the error?

Comment: Please include your relevant GHA workflow steps in your question.